# Two equations identical but opposite signs have the same Maclaurin series in Mathematica: Is that possible?

Tags: series-expansion

I have two equations

```
Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y^(5/2) Sqrt[y - 4 Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y^(3/2) + 2 y^2]
```

and

```
y^(5/2) (Sqrt[y] - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y - 2 y^(3/2))
```

When plotted over a set of values of interest the results are of opposite sign:

```
Plot[{Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y^(5/2) Sqrt[y - 4 Sqrt[1 - 2 y]  y^(3/2) + 2 y^2],
  y^(5/2) (Sqrt[y] - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y - 2 y^(3/2))},
 {y, 1/3, (2 + Sqrt[2])/8},
 PlotLegends -> {"Sqrt[1-2y] \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(5/2\)]\) \
Sqrt[y-4 Sqrt[1-2y]  y^(3/2)+2 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]",
    "y^(5/2)(Sqrt[y]-2Sqrt[1-2y]y-2y^(3/2))"}]
```

[image: Plot of two functions with opposite signs]

But when I take a Maclaurin series, the series look identical rather than having opposite signs:

```
Series[Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y^(5/2) Sqrt[y - 4 Sqrt[1 - 2 y]  y^(3/2) + 2 y^2], {y, 0, 10}] // Normal
```

[image: Series 1]

```
Series[y^(5/2) (Sqrt[y] - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 y] y - 2 y^(3/2)), {y, 0, 10}] // Normal
```

[image: Series 2]

Am I just not understanding some basic mathematics?

Comment: Let $f$ and $g$ be your 1st and 2nd expressions.  The problem may have to do with a discontinuity in $\frac{df}{dx}$ at y=1/6 .  The two expressions may be equal on {0, 1/6} where the MacLaurin is valid and have opposite signs in the region {1/6, 1/2} .  Use `Plot[{f, g}, {y, .1, .2}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]`  and `FunctionDomain[D[f, y], y, Reals]` to see the discontinuity.

Comment: @LouisB Thanks!  That makes sense.

Comment: Plot them from 0 instead of 1/3. Point being, they agree in a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your comments that solved my issue but I’m voting to close this question because it turns out to be a mathematics question (i.e. me not remembering my real analysis decades ago) and not an issue with *Mathematica*.